# Is it possible to host plain HTML files in Google Apps?

Tags: web-hosting, google-workspace

I'd like to upload a handful of HTML files that I want to replace an existing Google Site.

I know I can edit the HTML for each page in Google Sites, but I can't just upload my HTML files or even copy-paste them.  I have CSS files and JS files as well.

Is it even possible in Google Apps? Or do I have to use a 3rd-party web host?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AppEngine can host static files, and can be mapped to a subdomain of your Google Apps domain (ie, if you have example.com, you can make your appengine app be static.example.com, or www.example.com).

You'll need a [tiny amount of python](http://www.terminally-incoherent.com/blog/2009/02/23/your-homepage-on-google-appengine/) (or java) code to make it work.

Comment: Ah, yes, thanks!  I was pondering that, after I posted my question.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that's not possible with Google Apps. You can try [Microsoft Office Live Small Business](http://smallbusiness.officelive.com). Once signed up (it's free), activate the third-party design tools option to use upload directly into the web folder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can host your own html on Google Sites this in any way that I know of. I tried importing an html file as an "attachment" (this is what Google Sites seem to call any files intended for site visitors to download). Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Looks like they actively don't want you to use the service this way.

If you want to host a basic site for free, there are several site builders out there (including Google Sites) that let you do this. I checked out the one I use (weebly) and it seems they don't let you load an uploaded html page as a normal page either. Looks like preventing people from uploading content not created via the site builder itself. One workaround might be creating a blank template & uploading all content via the "custom html" tag.

This isn't what free site builders are intended for though & may not work forever. If you want to host an actual site, you'd probably be better off with something built for that purpose.